# Solve the integral?

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Help me? please How to solve this integral?
$$\int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx$$

Comment: There is a *very* strictly defined list of basic steps to make, to integrate a rational function. Are you aware of it? Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: Hi @Erka. Welcome! [You might find this helpful](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?lq=1).

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1-\sqrt2x+x^2}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+\sqrt2x+x^2}\tag{1}\\
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(\sqrt2x-1\right)^2+1}+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(\sqrt2x+1\right)^2+1}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2x-1)+\tan^{-1}(\sqrt2x+1)\right)+C\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt2x}{1-x^2}\right)+C\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: partial fractions
$(2)$: complete square
$(3)$: arctan integral
$(4)$: tan of a sum formula

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\int\frac{\frac1{x^2}+1}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}dx$$

As $\displaystyle\int\left(\frac1{x^2}+1\right)dx=x-\frac1x$

write $\displaystyle x^2+\frac1{x^2}=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2 $ and set $\displaystyle x-\frac1x=u$

Then use [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

Comment: @Erka, May I request you to establish the equivalence of the two answers?