# What is the sum of 1(1 - 1/3 ) - 1/2(1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7)+1/3(1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11) - 1/4(...)...?

Tags: convergence-divergence

The series converges (conditionally) since 
$$
1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}+\ldots
$$
converges to $\ln{2}$, and 
$$
1 - \frac{1}{3},\quad 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7},\quad 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{11}... 
$$is a monotonically increasing sequence with a limit of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  However I have made no progress at all in finding an expression for its sum. Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.

Comment: A power-series method seems to work, i.e. define $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$ take the derivative and sum the series and then integrate. Using this we can write the sum, $f(1)$, as the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(2) - \log(1+x^4)}{1+x^2}{\rm d}x$

Comment: To lazy to play with integrals tonight so I tried to evaluate it using Mathematical software instead and it gives the result $$\frac{C}{2} + \frac{\pi}{32}\log(577 - 408\sqrt{2}) + i \left[\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2+\sqrt{2}}\right) - \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-i}{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]\simeq 0.4474$$ where $C$ is the Catalan constant and $\text{Li}_2$ is the diogarithm. It is possible to simplify the last part using various polylog identities to make it explicitly real.

Comment: If we set
$$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
then $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the Taylor series of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x(1-x^2)}$ and by the Discrete Fourier Transform the wanted series is
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan((-x)^{1/4})}{(-x)^{3/4}(1+(-x)^{3/2})}-\frac{\text{arctanh}((-x)^{1/4})}{(-x)^{3/4}(1-(-x)^{3/2})}\right)\,dx $$

Comment: Many thanks to Winther, D'Aurizio & Splutterwit for their helpful work, speedily produced. It has take me a while to digest all this.  I will now focus on the integral arrived at by Winther & Splutterwit, each using a different method. Thanks also to D'Aurizio for needed editing.

Answer (score 2):

As Winthers has pointed out, the required sum $S$ is given by the following integral
$$S = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln 2 - \ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (2) - \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (2) - J.$$

I will now find the integral $J$ using the most elementary means possible.

We begin by considering the integral $\displaystyle{\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx}$. Writing this as
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx + \int^\infty_1 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx.$$
If in the right most integral we set $x \mapsto 1/x$ one obtains
\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx &= \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx + \int^1_0 \frac{ \ln \left (1 + \frac{1}{x^4} \right )}{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}} \frac{dx}{x^2}\\
&= 2 \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx - 4 \int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{1 + x^2} \, dx.
\end{align*}

Now for the right most integral appearing above, integrating by parts yields
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln x}{1 + x^2} \, dx = - \int^1_0 \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{x} \, dx = - \mathbf{G},$$
where $\mathbf{G}$ is Catalan's constant and comes from one of the [well-known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html) integral representations for this constant. Thus, after rearranging, we have
$$J = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx - 2 \mathbf{G}.$$
Now it remains to determine the integral $\displaystyle{\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx}$.

Let
$$I(a) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + ax^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx, \quad a \geqslant 0.$$
Our required integral is recovered on setting $a = 1$. Differentiating under the integral sign with respect to the parameter $a$, we have
$$I'(a) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^4}{(1 + ax^4)(1 + x^2)} \, dx,$$
which, under a partial fraction decomposition becomes
$$I'(a) = \frac{1}{a + 1} \int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} + \frac{1}{a + 1} \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^2}{1 + ax^4} \, dx - \frac{1}{a + 1} \int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{1 + a x^4}.$$
Finding these three integrals. The first is trivial. It is
$$I_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
The second and third can be found by converting them into the form of beta functions.

For the second integral, on setting $t = a x^4$ it may be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
I_2 &= \frac{1}{4 a^{3/4}} \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{-1/4}}{1 + t} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{4 a^{3/4}} \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{3/4 - 1}}{(1 + t)^{3/4 + 1/4}} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{4 a^{3/4}} \text{B} \left (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right ).
\end{align*}
And since
$$\text{B} \left (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \Gamma \left (\frac{3}{4} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{4} \right ) = \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{4} \right ) \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{4} \right ) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \left (\frac{\pi}{4} \right )} = \pi \sqrt{2},$$
where use has been made of *Euler's reflection formula*, we arrive at
$$I_2 = \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4 a^{3/4}}.$$
The third integral can be found in an exactly analogous manner to how the second was found. The result is
$$I_3 = \frac{\pi \sqrt{\pi}}{4 a^{1/4}}.$$
So
$$I'(a) = \frac{\pi}{2 (a + 1)} + \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4 a^{3/4} (a + 1)} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4 a^{1/4} (a + 1)}.$$

We require $I(1)$. As $I(0) = 0$, on integrating up with respect to $a$ from zero to one we have
$$I(1) = \frac{\pi}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{da}{a + 1} + \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4} \int^1_0 \frac{da}{a^{3/4} (a + 1)} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4} \int^1_0 \frac{da}{a^{1/4} (a + 1)}.$$
Each of these three integrals can be readily found. The first is
$$I_\alpha = \int^1_0 \frac{da}{a + 1} = \ln (2).$$
For the second and the third, after a substitution of $a = x^4$ is made we have (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394710/how-to-compute-int-01-frac11x4-dx) for its evaluation)
$$I_\beta = 4 \int^1_0 \frac{dx}{1 + x^4} = \frac{\pi + \ln (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}},$$ 
and (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596710/solve-the-integral) for its evaluation)
$$I_\gamma = 4 \int^1_0 \frac{1 + x^2}{1 + x^4} \, dx = \frac{\pi - \ln (3 + 2\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

So finally we have
\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4}{1 + x^2} \, dx &= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \ln (2) + \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi + \ln (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi - \ln (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \ln (6 + 4\sqrt{2}).
\end{align*}
Thus 
$$J = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (6 + 4 \sqrt{2}) - 2 \mathbf{G}.$$

So our sum, in closed formed, becomes
$$S = \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (2) - \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (6 + 4 \sqrt{2}) + 2\mathbf{G} = 2 \mathbf{G} - \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \ln (3 + 2 \sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: Using elementary means, $J = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx$ may also be evaluated by expressing $1 + x^4$ in terms of $1 + x^2$ thus:

Comment: Using elementary means, $J = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^4)}{1 + x^2} \, dx$ may also be evaluated by expressing $1 + x^4$ in terms of $1 + x^2$ thus: $$J = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 + x^2)^2 - 2(1 + x^2) +2}{1 + x^2} \, dx$$. The usual substitution $x = tany$ yields $$J = \int^pi/4_0\ ln (sec^4y - 2sec^2y +2) \, dy$$  $$= \int^pi/4_0 ln(sec^4y) \, dy +  \int^pi/4_0 ln(1 - 2cos^2y + cos^4y) \, dy$$ $$= -4 \int^pi/4_0 ln(cosy) \, dy +  \int^pi/4_0 ln(1 - 2cos^2(2y)sin^2(2y) \, dy$$ $$ = pi/2*ln2 - 2G + pi/2*ln(frac{\ln (1 + 1/sqrt(2))}{2} \$$  $$= pi/4ln(6+ sqrt(4)) - 2G $$

Comment: You will gather I haven't got the hang of the system here but the maths is valid!

Comment: $$J = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln ((1 + x^2)^2 - 2(1 + x^2) +2)}{1 + x^2}\, dx$$\\ 


$$ = \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\ ln (sec^4y - 2sec^2y +2) \, dy$$\\

$$= \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 ln(sec^4y) \, dy +  \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 ln(1 - 2cos^2y + 2cos^4y) \, dy$$\\

$$= -4\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 ln(cosy) \, dy +  \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 ln(1 - 2cos^22ysin^22y) \, dy$$\\

$$= {\frac{\pi}{2}}ln2 - 2G +  \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 ln(1 - 0.5sin^22\theta) \, d\theta$$\\

$$={\frac{\pi}{2}}ln2 - 2G + {\frac{\pi}{2}}ln({\frac{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{2}})$$\\

$$= {\frac{\pi}{4}}ln(6+ {\sqrt4}) - 2G $$

Comment: I hope this looks better, apologies to all

Comment: @Graham - Yes, it looks better now. Perhaps it would have been easier if you added it as an answer (or update) as your approach is indeed more elementary than mine.

Comment: My wrong, at the end of your integration "comment" seemed to be the only available option, one that I exercised badly.  It also looked appropriate; given that the integration had already been performed, it seemed that my contribution amounted to no more than a commment. I will figure out how I could have done an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
G=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{i} \sum_{j=0}^{2i} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1} y^{i} dy =\frac{1}{i}  \\ 
\int_{0}^{1} x^{2j+1} dx = \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute these & perform the geometric sums, do the y integrals ... we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
G=\frac{\pi}{4} \ln2- \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^4)}{(1+x^2)} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
The value of the integral is roughly $0.09690 \cdots$ & $G=0.4475 \cdots$ (In agreement with Winther).
I am not sure how to do this integral at the moment, but given that $1+x^4=(1+\sqrt{2}x+x^2)(1-\sqrt{2}x+x^2)$ it certainly give a clue where the logarithmic term in Winthers answer comes from.